# Can´t call few times a method same object PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to access the same method twice without having to create the object twice. I made this code

```
    <?php 
class help{

  public $cn;
  public function __construct(){
    require_once 'connection.php';
    $this->cn = $c;// now $ cn brings the DB connection
  }


  public function executeQuery( $q ){
    self::__construct(); /*I added it because according to I was trying to 
                           invoke again the method without creating a 
                           previous object, if I take it off, it marks me as 
                           if there was no $ cn*/
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    mysqli_set_charset($this->cn, "utf8");
    return mysqli_query( $this->cn, $q );
  }

}

  $h = new help();
  $q = "INSERT INTO FOOBAR (foo_id, bar_id) VALUES('foo','bar')";//new record
  $r = $h->executeQuery( $q );//I will do something with $r
  $q = "SELECT * FROM FOOBAR";//I retrive all records but the query fails
  echo $h->executeQuery( json_encode( $q ) );;
 ?>
```

Now, the object does not have a constructor, and if it does not pass the self :: __ construct (); Send me that $ cn is not declared.

How do I solve it? Will I have to create two objects?

Thank you

**EDIT**
This is my connection.

```
<?php
global $c;
$c = mysqli_connect("localhost","foo","bar","myDB");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

Comment: Please link your `connection.php`file (without the reals credentials of course)

Comment: ready, but I´m not sure if the problem is the connection

Comment: Don't use a global for your database connection. Use Dependency Injection to pass it into your class.

Comment: Your should separate your logic, set an HTTP header, modify php configuration, modify mysql charset inside an `executeQuery` into an `help` class. That look like a bazar function ^^'

Comment: Opposed to what @Mcsky has said.. we need the real values for your connection.

Comment: @Samuel Why do you need the real credentials ?

Comment: @Mcsky, Troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a `require_once()` call, which is your problem.  You will not re-include the file the second time it's called, but being that you're not pulling a global variable, whatever was returned from the first include is not available to you the second time around.

If it's okay to include the file multiple times, you can make the `require_once` a plain `require` and that will set your variable as you are expecting.